# ModuleError, BadState

Tags: pallet, runtime, staking, error

#### Setup

I'm currently integrating staking functionality into my pallet. Here is a snipped of the relevant part:

```
let who = ensure_signed(origin.clone())?;
let required_stake = T::RequiredStake::get();
let controller: <<T as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source =
                        T::Lookup::unlookup(who.clone());
let payee = RewardDestination::Staked;
<pallet_staking::Pallet<T>>::bond(origin, controller, required_stake, payee)?;
```

where `T::RequiredStake` is just some amount of balance,
so this all compiles fine.

The abbreviated test runtime looks like this:

```
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum TestRuntime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        VoterList: pallet_bags_list,
        Staking: pallet_staking,
        ShelfCommittees: crate,
    }
);

impl pallet_staking::Config for TestRuntime {
    type Currency = Balances;
    type CurrencyBalance = Balance;
    type UnixTime = Timestamp;
    type CurrencyToVote = U128CurrencyToVote;
    type GenesisElectionProvider = NoElection<(AccountId, BlockNumber, Staking, ())>;
    type ElectionProvider = NoElection<(AccountId, BlockNumber, Staking, ())>;
    type MaxNominations = MaxNominations;
    type RewardRemainder = ();
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Slash = ();
    type Reward = ();
    type SessionsPerEra = SessionsPerEra;
    type BondingDuration = BondingDuration;
    type SlashDeferDuration = SlashDeferDuration;
    type SessionInterface = ();
    type EraPayout = ();
    type NextNewSession = ();
    type MaxNominatorRewardedPerValidator = MaxNominatorRewardedPerValidator;
    type OffendingValidatorsThreshold = OffendingValidatorsThreshold;
    type TargetList = UseValidatorsMap<Self>;
    type MaxUnlockingChunks = ConstU32<32>;
    type HistoryDepth = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<84>;
    type BenchmarkingConfig = StakingBenchmarkingConfig;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_staking::weights::SubstrateWeight<TestRuntime>;
    type VoterList = VoterList;
    type OnStakerSlash = ();
    type AdminOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
}
```

#### Problem

When testing with a mock runtime I get the following error (abbreviated):

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Module(ModuleError { index: 4, error: [17, 0, 0, 0], message: Some("BadState") })'
```

To me this is not clear what the error is supposed to represent.
I would have expected the staking pallet to throw some other error (e.g not enough free balance or similar), but not this.

Is there maybe some `GenesisConfig` I need to set for the staking pallet?

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: Can you share the runtime for your pallet as well. I think this might not be the ideal way you call another pallet. Instead include pallet_staking traits into the Config of your pallet. Then integrate both in your mock runtime and then call it.

Comment: I added the test runtime configuration in the post

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that the `bond` extrinsic of `pallet-staking` is attempting to call `inc_consumers` of `frame-system`, which checks if the accounts `providers` is greater than 0.
If this is not the case then `NoProviders` is returned, which the staking pallet maps to `BadState` which is a pretty bad error message IMO.

So making sure that `providers` for the account is at least 1 does the trick.
This can be done by calling `<frame_system::Pallet<T>>::inc_providers(who)`.